# How do I round a straight line with CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I want to round the straight line with CSS. But I wasn't successful. How can I do it? Thanks.

Screenshots :
- Design : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFvlX.jpg
- My Css Code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQNDc.jpg

```
.steps {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

    &:before {
       content: '';
       position: absolute;
       top: -130px;
       right: 50px;
       width: 30px;
       height: 1px;
       background-color: #eff0f1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Border-radius: 0 20px 0 0` is what you want.

Comment: @Azametzin Unfortunately. No change. :(

Comment: You could create a box with relevant dimensions and white background. Then set `border: 1px solid #eff0f1; border-left: 0; border-bottom: 0`; Position it where you want and finally apply the `border-radius` I commented before.

Comment: Thanks @Azametzin. I solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border-top-right-radius` on your border.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 3px solid grey;
  border-right: 3px solid grey;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `border-radius` it takes four numbers to round four angels of an element

```
border-radius: 5px 10px 15px 20px;
```

first is for top-left, second for top right, third right bottom, forth left bottom
use % for more line curve.

```css
div{
  border-radius:5px 10px 15px 20%;
  width:300px;
  height:80px;
  border:3px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```